# How to find difference between successive rows of same column in sql server using lag function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Been trying with the following query but i'm getting constant difference

```
with cte as 
(
select businessentityid,nationalidnumber,SickLeaveHours,LAG(sickleavehours) over (order by businessentityid) as PreviousRow
from HumanResources.Employee
)
select *,DIFFERENCE(sickleavehours,cte.previousrow) from cte
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just do this?:

```
with cte as 
(
select businessentityid,nationalidnumber,SickLeaveHours,LAG(sickleavehours) over (order by businessentityid) as PreviousRow
from HumanResources.Employee
)
select *, sickleavehours - cte.previousrow as difference from cte
```